# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm at the newest level on Android. just boot up a new project and got error on the Gradle Build with Pie ( Android v9.0):

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

this is my `build.gradle (Module:app)`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

How do I do next?

Comment: [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) will solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try migrating to Androidx

```
Android Studio > Refactor Menu > Migrate to AndroidX...
```

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library):

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version
>   of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The
>   AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also
>   includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts
>   (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*)
>   will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library
>   development will occur in the AndroidX library.
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>   should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using support library which was last released for API 28 but you are trying to find API 29 version of this library. API 29 version of this library was moved to another library called AndroidX.

Goto Menu bar in Android Studio, Select Refactor then Migrate to AndroidX, that should solve the issue.

[image]

This will replace any old support library packages that you are using with newer AndroidX versions.
If you get any error in your dependencies after Migrating, find your dependency packages from the following lik and replace them with the newer ones listed in table:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate